# NetBeans cannot find symbol class

Tags: java, for-loop, netbeans

I was working on a java project in NetBeans and after I have written a few blocks of code one day I tried to continue my work but a problem came up. the problem is that I cannot write a single line of code without getting the error shown in the image. Moreover, I tried to work on other previous completed projects but every time I inserted (for example ) a for loop I was getting the same error. I tried to solve it by clearing the cache but it did not help me. I believe it has something to do with NetBeans but I do not know what.

[image]

Comment: 1) Post some code instead of a picture. 2) You have to place the for-statement inside any method which executes it.

Comment: As mentioned, it appears you're trying to put code outside of any method. That is illegal in Java.

Comment: I posted the photo so you can see the error. So I created a new project and inside that a new class  and wrote the code above. I get the same error in the for loop   _______                                                                                                                                                


package test;

/**
 *
 * @author nikos
 */
public class Sample {
    
    int x;

    public Sample(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

   for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
   {
       System.out.println(i);
   }
    
    
    
    
}

Comment: @NikosKokkoris I would suggest learning java by following a tutorial

Comment: *So I created a new project and inside that a new class and wrote the code above.* -> your little code sample **again** has the `for` outside of a method.

Comment: @NikosKokkoris: Picture accompanied the code to show the error is fine. But the code **must** be included.

Comment: Please, post the code you are having trouble with. **The code**, not a photograph of the code. This is a programming site, not a photography site. We want to copy&paste&debug your code, not critique its use of color and perspective. You are expecting us to do your work for you, for free, in our spare time, and you are not even willing to put in the half second of work required to post your code, instead you expect everybody who wants to answer this question to type the code in themselves. That is, frankly, arrogant and impolite.

Comment: So my mind got in order. i realized my very stupid mistake . Thank you guys for sparing your time for such a stupid mistake.

Comment: @NikosKokkoris: Not mistake is stupid since we learn from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any `for-loop`, `while-loop`, `if-statement` etc. must be placed *inside* a method, constructor or a static block - briefly said it must be inside a block defined with `{ }`.

You put the `for-loop` between the constructor and the `play_game` method. If you want to execute the loop directly after the instantiation of the object, place it into the constructor or a method which is called by a constructor.

```
public Player(...) {

     // getters & setters

     for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
         System.out.println(i);
     }
}
```

Comment: Any statement must be inside a block. Would probably be the most fitting description